EFSecondLevelCache serialization issue
I am trying to add second-level caching to my dbcontext. I am using PostgreSQL with quite a lot of JSON fields. Some have converters of their own. And they are added to the mix like this:
var dataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(connectionString);
dataSourceBuilder
    .ConfigureJsonOptions(CustomJsonSerializationOptions.ContractOptions)
    .EnableDynamicJson()
    .UseNodaTime()
    ;

var dataSource = dataSourceBuilder.Build();

builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<T>((serviceProvider, options) =>
{
    options
        .UseExceptionProcessor()
        .UseNpgsql(dataSource, o => o.ConfigureOptions(migrationHistoryTableName, migrationAssembly))
        ;
    options.AddInterceptors(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SecondLevelCacheInterceptor>());
});

This part works as expected. When trying to add second-level caching (memory cache only for now), I am registering that service like this:
services.AddEFSecondLevelCache(options =>
            options.UseMemoryCacheProvider()
                .CacheAllQueries(CacheExpirationMode.Absolute, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
                .ConfigureLogging(true)
                .UseCacheKeyPrefix("EF_")
                .UseJsonSerializerOptions(CustomJsonSerializationOptions.ContractOptions)
        );

However, indifferent to adding or not adding .UseJsonSerializerOptions at the end here I get deserialization exception regarding a type that has a converter in my ContractOptions. It is evident, that the options are not used at all (with memory cache it makes no sense to apply any serialization at all, but that's another topic).
If I remove .AddInterceptor everything works like a charm.
[Update]
Fix on the way: https://github.com/VahidN/EFCoreSecondLevelCacheInterceptor/issues/259
